# Cannot use system font in XeLaTeX (macOS)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, macos

I'm under macOS 12.4, the following code worked fine for me before

```tex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"

% contents...

\setmonofont[Mapping={}]{Monaco}
```

but after I reinstall my system and manually reinstall `MacTex` and use `Texpad` as the writing tool, this line breaks

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "Monaco" cannot be found.
```

I've searched for almost half a day and could not solve, any help plzzz  thanks in advance

Comment: Basic question, but did you check whether the Monaco font is available as a monofont in the system? Use Font Book for make sure. On my computer (macOS 12), Monaco is only available as normal, not mono.

Comment: @Miyase That makes no difference. You can set any font or fontface to be the mono font.

Comment: Apologies, you're right. I just tried with the default Monaco font provided by macOS, it works without error, both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Checking that the font is installed at all is still a good step, anyway. ;)